# Java jdom doesn't print all elements, prints empty string

Tags: java, xml, pom.xml, element, document

First, I've got xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<bookshelf>
    <book ISBN="c01" press="AD press">
        <book>Oracle</book>
        <Author>Smith</Author>
        <price>32.00</price>
    </book>
    <book ISBN="b11" press="XY press">
        <book>Android</book>
        <Author>Smith</Author>
        <price>35.00</price>
    </book>
</bookshelf>
```

Then having java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(currentPath + "/book.xml");
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    System.out.println("begin");
    Node n = document.getElementsByTagName("book").item(i);
    Element e = (Element) n;
    System.out.println(e.getAttribute("ISBN"));
    System.out.println(e.getAttribute("press"));
    System.out.println("end");
}
```

Then it prints:

```
begin
b11
XY press
end
begin


end
```

It's weird to me:

(1) Why the first element printed is "b11" but not "c01"? It's the first element.

(2) Why only one "book" element is printed, the other is empty?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) Why the first element printed is "b11" but not "c01"? It's the first element.

It didn't, for me. I got `c01` and then a blank entry, which makes sense given the input.

> (2) Why only one "book" element is printed, the other is empty?

Because you have `book` elements within other `book` elements. `getElementsByTagName` returns all four of them. The second one is the one nested within the first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<bookshelf>
    <book ISBN="c01" press="AD press">      #1 (index 0)
        <book>Oracle</book>                 #2 (index 1)
        <Author>Smith</Author>
        <price>32.00</price>
    </book>
    <book ISBN="b11" press="XY press">      #3 (index 2)
        <book>Android</book>                #4 (index 3)
        <Author>Smith</Author>
        <price>35.00</price>
    </book>
</bookshelf>
```

I'm not that familiar with this specific API, but if I get the `bookshelf` and then loop its children and pick out the ones that are `book`s, I get the expected output:

```java
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

class Example {
    public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse("book.xml");
        NodeList bookshelves = document.getElementsByTagName("bookshelf");
        if (bookshelves.getLength() > 0) {
            Element bookshelf = (Element)bookshelves.item(0);
            NodeList children = bookshelf.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0, l = children.getLength(); i < l; ++i) {
                Node child = children.item(i);
                if (child.getNodeName().equals("book")) {
                    Element book = (Element)child;
                    System.out.println(book.getAttribute("ISBN"));
                    System.out.println(book.getAttribute("press"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That code assumes a single bookshelf, obviously adapt as needed. It doesn't assume just two `bookshelf > book` elements, it lists as many as there are.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of nested `<book>` tag. Since `<book>` tag inside `<book>`, parser considers `<book>Oracle</book>` as second record.

```
 <book ISBN="c01" press="AD press">
        <book>Oracle</book> //<book> tag inside <book>
        <Author>Smith</Author>
        <price>32.00</price>
    </book>
```

Answer (score 0):

your xml is a bit wierd because  `<book>` represents two different things.

My advise is to mark you document more readable with `<title>` for the title and not `<book>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<bookshelf>
    <book ISBN="c01" press="AD press">
        <title>Oracle</title>
        <Author>Smith</Author>
        <price>32.00</price>
    </book>
    <book ISBN="b11" press="XY press">
        <title>Android</title>
        <Author>Smith</Author>
        <price>35.00</price>
    </book>
</bookshelf>
```